# Convert String to Date in Formula Field (and then get the YEAR)

Tags: formula-field, date, string

In our project, we have this Date-Key (which is a TEXT FIELD) in which we input dates with the ff. format:

dd-MM-yyyy

MM-yyyy

yyyy

Now in our custom object, we also have a formula(text) field that will retrieve the YEAR from the text field above.

The formula that I created is (I still don't know how to get the Year):

```
TEXT( DATEVALUE(Date_Key__c) )
```

I was hoping it would work but I only get #Error! in my Formula field.

Example:

Date_Key__c = 19-1-2016

formula(text) = #Error!

I was hoping that I would get 19-1-2016 and from their also retrieve the year which is 2016.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a text field, do a string operation on it to remove all but the last four numeric characters which will leave you with the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm) you will need your format to be:

```
DATEVALUE( "YYYY-MM-DD" )
```

> You can also convert text to a Date so you can use the string value
>   with your other Date fields and formulas. You’ll want your text to be
>   formatted as “YYYY-MM-DD”...

If you are only needing the year from the existing text then you can use the RIGHT function described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#RIGHT).

```
RIGHT(Date_Key__c, 4)
```

Comment: Oh wow this is amazing! Your last suggestion is the thing that I've been looking for! Thank you very much! I'll also change the date format for Date_Key__c to YYYY-MM-DD just in case we need to get the DATEVALUE in the future. For now the LEFT(Date_Key__c, 4) works for us. Again thanks!

Comment: I get the right result when using below formula in detail page, whereas in the report on related list it shows as "#Error!" - any idea?

Formula: DATEVALUE(date1__c ) -  DATEVALUE(date2__c). 
Both fields are text data type containing datetime value.